# Opencart - How to hide option price for certain options only?

Tags: php, opencart

I have a OpenCart 1.5.6.4 shop which displays few options for each products.

I would like to hide prices for some selected options (not all).

You can refer this screenshot for better understanding:

[image]

Comment: the image you linked didn't really help, but i did see a pole dancer so i guess that's a plus.

Comment: please check this third party module. http://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=extension/extension/info&extension_id=12331

Comment: @HarnishDesign, but that hides all options price, i just want to hide for few

Answer (score 1):

1. You need to add a checkbox in your options "Hide Price"
2. Add a new field in data base and then store its value in it (most probably product_options) table.
3. In the controller, get its value along with other values.
4. In tpl, add a condition around price that `if (hide_price!=0) { echo $price; }`